# Splitting string based on only a specific delimiter

Tags: mysql, sql, string, split, mysql-workbench

I'm trying to split a field (at some delimiter ';') and insert the results into a table.
The maximum is 5 substrings delimited by ';' . There will only be a maximum of 5 fruits.
Given only the fruit column, how can I split the string to get the separate fruits. If there are lesser fruits than 5, remaining columns will return NA.

| fruits | fruit1 | fruit2 | fruit3 | fruit4 | fruit5 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| apple; orange; banana | apple | orange | banana | -null- | -null- |
| apple; orange; pine-apple; dragon-fruit; banana | apple | orange | pine-apple | dragon-fruit | banana |
| pear/grape ; orange; banana; strawberry | pear/grape | orange | banana | strawberry | -null- |
| apple; blueberry; kiwi/lemon | apple | blueberry | kiwi/lemon | -null- | -null- |

I 1st created new columns and set it all to null.
I have tried the following code but it does not work, if there are less fruits than columns, the remaining columns will just take the values of the last fruit instead of null.

```
SELECT  
fruits,
  SUBSTRING_INDEX(fruits, ';', 1) AS 'fruit1',
  CASE 
    WHEN LOCATE(';', fruits, LENGTH(fruit1)+1) = 0 THEN NULL 
    ELSE SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(fruits, ';', 2), ';', -1)
  END AS 'fruit2',
  CASE 
    WHEN LOCATE(';', fruits, LENGTH(fruit1)+LENGTH(fruit2)+1) = 0 THEN NULL 
    WHEN LOCATE(';', fruits, (LOCATE(';', fruits, LENGTH(fruit1)) + 2)) = 0 THEN NULL
    ELSE SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(fruits, ';', 3), ';', -1)
  END AS 'fruit3',
  CASE 
    WHEN LOCATE(';', fruits, LENGTH(fruit1) + LENGTH(fruit2) + LENGTH(fruit3) + 3) = 0 THEN NULL 
    WHEN LOCATE(';', fruits, (LOCATE(';', fruits,  LENGTH(fruit1) + LENGTH(fruit2) + LENGTH(fruit3)+2) + 1)) = 0 THEN NULL
    ELSE SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(fruits, ';', 4), ';', -1)
  END AS 'fruit4'
  FROM TABLENAME;
```

Is there any more information to split the string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In MySQL 5.7 and 8.0, JSON functions are now supported. You could do some string-manipulation to turn this:

```
apple; orange; banana
```

into this:

```
["apple", "orange", "banana"]
```

Then use JSON functions to extract a specific array element by position.

```
mysql> set @s = 'apple; orange; banana';

mysql> select cast(concat('["', replace(@s, '; ', '","'), '"]') as json) as array;
+-------------------------------+
| array                         |
+-------------------------------+
| ["apple", "orange", "banana"] |
+-------------------------------+


mysql> select json_unquote(json_extract(
    cast(concat('["', replace(@s, '; ', '","'), '"]') as json),
    '$[1]')) as element;
+---------+
| element |
+---------+
| orange  |
+---------+
```

Then you can extract `'$[2]'` or `'$[3]'` or any other element. You could use the `->>` shortcut for extract-and-unquote.

```
SELECT  
  fruits,
  fruits->>'$[0]' AS `fruit1`,
  fruits->>'$[1]' AS `fruit2`,
  fruits->>'$[2]' AS `fruit3`,
  fruits->>'$[3]' AS `fruit4`
FROM (
  SELECT CAST(CONCAT('["', REPLACE(fruits, '; ', '","'), '"]')) AS fruits
  FROM TABLENAME
) AS f;
```

You might consider storing the list as a JSON columns, instead of your current semicolon-separated string format.